# Getting html data attribute string even its value boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

This is my html;

```
<div id="myDiv" data-status="@Model.Approved"> </div>
```

in javascript side;

```
var currentStatus = $("#myDiv").data('status');
```

currentStatus is always string "False" or "True" according to model.Approved, but i want to get it as boolean like true or false.

How can i do it can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like following using `===` operator.

```
var currentStatus = $("#myDiv").data('status')==="True";
```

**Update:** to get `null` do this.

```
var status = $("#myDiv").data('status');
var currentStatus;

if (status == "True") {
    currentStatus = true;
} else if (status == "False") {
    currentStatus = false;
} else {
    currentStatus = null;
}
```

Comment: Whenever using `===` is possible, use it! It's just good practice, imo.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated my answer. @Rein

Comment: @Model.Approved is nullable , so when it returns " " i want to get null value